# StdOut.println not prints blank line

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

For some reason, when I try to print my *champ* variable, the vscode debugger just prints a new line:

```java
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;

public class RandomWord {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String champ = "";
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        champ += StdIn.readString();
    };
    StdOut.println(champ);
  }
}
```

I don't know if this is an issue with the way I initialized my champ variable, or something else.

You can find the code for those classes [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/javadoc/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdOut.html).

Comment: What happens if you run it on the command line? There's nothing wrong with your java code, and vscode debugger doesn't randomly break apps. Most likely StdIn/StdOut don't work like you think they do, or there's an empty line at the start, so that while loop fails immediately, and champ remains empty as a consequence.

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be going wrong here as those `edu.princeton.cs.algs4` classes are definitely not standard and thus we don't how they are supposed to work (and whether there might be bugs or not).

Comment: Yes @Thomas You can [read here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/javadoc/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdOut.html) about how the package has defined the method

Comment: @rzwitserloot When I run it in the command prop the same thing happens.

Comment: @rzwitserloot also, when I run the print inside the while loop it works, plus I have used this method before.

Comment: I found that you need to use ctrl-z in order to stop the program from waiting for input. After this happens, the code works as expected.